# Grub error while installing Windows

Tags: grub2, windows

I have changed my HD with a new one (the old one was dead). When I try to install Windows 7 from DVD it won't boot, even if DVD is the 1st boot device in BIOS.

I always get the error message :

> Grub error no such partition
>   Update: i had an HD in my laptop ,i romve it and i put a new one clean on it and a have this Grub error

Any help?

Comment: Why do you have GRUB in the new HD? Does it have Ubuntu as well? Please edit the question to elaborate.

Comment: You need to install Windows, and then Ubuntu, I imagine you are trying to set up a dual-boot scenario?

Comment: i cant install windows it wont boot from DVD i dont wont to install dualboot i need just win 7

Answer (score 0):

***Note:  Always make sure that you have a backup of all your data when dealing with partitions.***

The short answer, boot with the Ubuntu live CD, choose try Ubuntu.  Go to disk utility, and delete the partition(s) that you want.  Remove the CD, and boot from the Windows 7 DVD, and it should be OK.

For the [Windows way](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)